# printing event xml file in text format c#

Tags: c#, printing

I am saving my data into an xml file. now, I am trying to print out the data saved in an xml file in text format. how should I do?

This is my code in printing.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog dlg = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog();
        dlg.PrinterSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();                        
    }

    delegate DialogResult ShowPrintDialog();
    private void printToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();
        dlg.ShowDialog();
        ShowPrintDialog spd = new ShowPrintDialog(dlg.ShowDialog);
        this.BeginInvoke(spd);            
    }
```

This is my code for saving the data to an XML file.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Document\\SliceEngine\\SliceEngine\\bin\\Debug\\saya.xml");
            XmlElement contentElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Patient");

            XmlElement levelEl = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LevelPriority");
            XmlText xmlText = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(berjaya[1]);
            levelEl.AppendChild(xmlText);
            contentElement.AppendChild(levelEl);
            xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(contentElement);                

            XmlElement nameEl = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Name");
            nameEl.InnerText = berjaya[3];                
            contentElement.AppendChild(nameEl);
            xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(contentElement);

            XmlElement idEl = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Id");
            idEl.InnerText = berjaya[39];
            contentElement.AppendChild(idEl);
            xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(contentElement);

            XmlElement bpEl = xmlDoc.CreateElement("BloodPressure");
            bpEl.InnerText = berjaya[5];                
            contentElement.AppendChild(bpEl);
            xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(contentElement);
```

I also do splitting data by using `berjaya[39]` so, I think the splitting can be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to do custom printing with Windows Forms, the class that does most of the work is the [PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument) class.  You'll need to create an instance of this class, and set the PrintDialog's PrintDocument property to the newly created instance.

Printing can be complicated.  The steps required to create a custom print job for an XML file are too complex to list in an answer here, but I can at least point you in the right direction.  I'd take a look at this page here on [printing with Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt36c58.aspx).